# Including a javascript function in a custom joomla module

Tags: javascript, php, joomla3.0

I have a working codepen that uses some javascript
https://codepen.io/cbold/pen/jOWONKO

I am struggling to understand the correct method/syntax for including the javascript function with my custom Joomla module.

I have read the official documentation but it does not make it any clearer for me

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page

I have also looked at several other similar questions posted on Stackoverflow, but I do not understand any of the examples/answers enough to apply them to my module.

I have tried to include the function as a separate file, and invoke it with my mod_mymodule.php :

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript(JURI::root(true)."modules/mod_mymodule/js/ mod_mymodule.js");
```

This is the javascript in mod_mymodule.js:

```
function clickHandler(target) {
    // Get the element that should be selected
    const elem = document.querySelector(target);
    // There were no elements to be selected
    if (!elem) return;
    // Get the old selected element (if any)
    const prevElem = document.querySelector('.selected');
    if (prevElem) {
        // If there was a previously selected element, it isn't anymore
        prevElem.classList.remove('selected');
    }
    // Make the new element selected
    elem.classList.add('selected');
}
```

The function does not occur.

I have tried both document.querySelector(target); and document.querySelector('#target');

I have also tried including the function at the end of my module’s default.php

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function clickHandler(target) {
    // Get the element that should be selected
    const elem = document.querySelector(target);
    // There were no elements to be selected
    if (!elem) return;
    // Get the old selected element (if any)
    const prevElem = document.querySelector('.selected');
    if (prevElem) {
        // If there was a previously selected element, it isn't anymore
        prevElem.classList.remove('selected');
    }
    // Make the new element selected
    elem.classList.add('selected');
}
</script>
```

But no luck.

Again I have tried both document.querySelector(target); and document.querySelector('#target');

I am pretty certain my <script> is wrong, but I don’t know enough about javascript – specifically the proper syntax required by Joomla – in order to make it work directly from my module.php.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for my needs, a short script in the module's default.php

```
<script>
        jQuery('.target').click(function(){
                var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
                jQuery('body').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
                jQuery('#target'+id).addClass('selected');
        });
</script>
```